# Excel does not display formulas unless editing

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, ms-office

I created a generic excel in Apache poi that includes Formulas, Price values etc.
Here is the expected excel (columns that are 1428,78 241 etc are price format) which is `"\\" + "\u20BA" + "#,##0.00"`. 
[image: excel format 1]

When i download excel from my hosting(does not have domain) excel displays like

[image: excel format 2]

After I press enable editing, they show. My problem here is this, **why cant i display my formulas in preview mod?** 
And also I can not see generated excel from my phone as well
**Is there any settings to set for Workbook?** 
**Is hosting without ssl or without domain cause the problem due to security issues?**

Comment: Can you provide the exact formula that is not working?

Comment: Please read about [Recalculation of Formulas](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html#recalculation). Then try whether re-evaluating formulas with POI's FormulaEvaluator solves your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel does not evaluate formula cells in protected mode. Formulas can consume significant computing power on a client device and also may attempt to import external data, thus posing a potential security risk.

Instead, in protected mode Excel will display a cached value if it has already been calculated, otherwise the default value, `0.00` in your case.

Take this formula for example, `C1 = A1 + B1`.

[image]

Assuming you are using .xlsx format, the worksheet data is stored internally in a structure like this:

```
...
<!-- worksheet.xlsx!xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml -->
<sheetData>
    <row r="1">
        <c r="A1" t="n">
            <v>1.0</v>
        </c>
        <c r="B1" t="n">
            <v>2.0</v>
        </c>
        <c r="C1" t="n">
            <f>A1 + B1</f>
            <v>3.0</v>  <!-- This is the cached formula result -->
        </c>
    </row>
</sheetData>
...
```

In this example, `<v>3.0</v>` is the cached formula cell value.

You can use POI `XSSFFormulaEvaluator` to evaluate the formula cell and save the cached value so that it will be available in Excel protected mode.

```
// evaluate all formulas in the workbook
XSSFFormulaEvaluator evaluator = new XSSFFormulaEvaluator(workbook);
evaluator.evaluateAll();
```

A few further notes:

1. `evaluateAll()` only needs to be performed once before you save the workbook. See https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html#recalculation for more details.
2. POI is able to evaluate most, but not all Excel formulas.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had no idea excel does not calculate in preview and reads from cache. I implemented this solution and it worked